# Javascript timer not running when the app is in background for iphone5

Tags: javascript, html, ios6

I am running a javascript timer that play a beep sound in my web app built for iphone 5. The timer is working fine when the app is in foreground. But when the app moves to background the timer is not running and the beep sound is not getting played.

Below is my code.

```
  setInterval( function(){ 
               beepAudio.get(0).play(); 
            }, timeInterval);
```

beepAudio is the id of my audio tag embedded in the html page.

I tried setTimeout too, but doesn't help. The IOS version is 6.1.4.

Is there a way to run the timer when the app is in background for iphone 5 ?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

From [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) in the **Background Execution and Multitasking** section (**emphasis** added by me):

> In iOS 4 and later, multitasking allows apps to continue running in the background even after the user switches to another app while still preserving battery life as much as possible. **Most apps are moved to the suspended state shortly after entering the background.** Only apps that provide important services to the user are allowed to continue running for any amount of time.

Same document, regarding the **Suspended** state:

> The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not execute any code.

So what you're trying to does not seem possible.

Comment: So none of the javascript code can be executed while the app is in background ???